# Use computed column of stored procedure in same SP at other place

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just calculated number of working days in a month and multiplied it by 8 and stored  it as `BaseHours`. It is an SP which returns many columns including `BaseHours`. Now for an other column I want to use this `BaseHours` within the same SP but I get an error. I am using SQL Server.

> Invalid Column Name'basehours'

```
(case when f.employmenttype = 3 then
   (case when c.paqtyq > BaseHours then
             (c.paqtyq + (c.paqtyq - BaseHours)) * 0.5 
         else
             c.paqtyq 
    end)
   else
      BaseHours 
  end) as bhours
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please post your code and/or clarify your question.

Comment: Post some code to see where's the gritch.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL...?

Comment: Is it something like this you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864799/how-to-reuse-calculated-columns-avoiding-duplicating-the-sql-statement

Comment: **SHOW US** your entire stored procedure code! This snippet alone doesn't really show **how** you're "creating" your "computed column" as you call it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're not actually creating a computed column on an existing table, but rather are returning a computed column as part of a result set?

If so, you need to store the result set and not return it until after you're finished with it.

```
-- Create and store the result set
SELECT
  ...
INTO
  #temp
FROM
  ...

-- Do your checks
???

-- Return the result set
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #temp
```

**EDIT**  I'm still guessing a bit, but I think I may understand your issue...

You can't re-use an aliased column elsewhere in the select statement, so this won't work...

```
SELECT
  value * 1.15    AS price,
  price * 0.95    AS discounted_price
FROM
  stock_table
```

Instead you need to do it in two steps...

```
SELECT
  price,
  price * 0.95    AS discounted_price
FROM
(
  SELECT
    value * 1.15    AS price
  FROM
    stock_table
)
  AS prices
```

Or using a CTE, which I think is tidier...

```
WITH
  prices AS
(
  SELECT
    value * 1.15    AS price
  FROM
    stock_table
)
SELECT
  price,
  price * 0.95    AS discounted_price
FROM
  prices
```

Comment: i have just cacluted number of working days in a month and multiplied  it by 8 and stored  it  as basehours.it is an SP which returns many columns including BaseHours.now for an other column i want to use this  BaseHours...but I can't ...(case when f.employmenttype=3 then
 (case when c.paqtyq>BaseHours then
  (c.paqtyq+(c.paqtyq-BaseHours))*0.5 
 else
  c.paqtyq end)
else
 BaseHours end) as bhours

Comment: @SunilChy - See my edit, hope it helps, I'm out for the day now :)

Comment: Thanks Dems i was looking  for  this  scenario only..........let me implement it in my script...

Comment: @SunilChy: If this answer works for you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") as the correct answer.