# How to re-use two calculated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
   SELECT 

        day,
        SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit,
        SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
        TotalProfit/TotalRevenue AS ProfitMargin

    FROM table
```

It says ***TotalProfit* is not found as a column of *table***. I want to avoid to do SUM(profit)/ SUM(revenue)  because the real formula is much more complicated.

Comment: Repeat `SUM()`.  The calculation is not so complicated.  You should also throw `day` into a `GROUP BY` clause so the query can work.

Comment: As to Why: it has to do with order of operations.  in postgresql the select evaluation/operations can occur at the same time thus when profitMargin goes to be calculated TotalProfit and TotalRevenue are not defined yet (not yet in scope).  Similarly you can't use TotalProfit in a where clause as it executes before the select (thus not defined not in scope).  but it would be fine to put in a having or order by clause which occurs AFTER the select has been processed. (meaning the select alias is now in scope)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse calculated columns avoiding duplicating the sql statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864799/how-to-reuse-calculated-columns-avoiding-duplicating-the-sql-statement)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer Alias name in SElect Clause. You must use group by when using aggregate functions like sum

SELECT

```
    day,
    SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit,
    SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
    SUM(profit)/SUM(revenue) AS ProfitMargin

FROM table
```

Group By day

Answer (score 1):

Do the sum again like this:

```
 SELECT 
        day,
        SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit,
        SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue,
        SUM(profit)/SUM(revenue) AS ProfitMargin

    FROM table
    GROUP BY Day
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to use previously declared alias use subquery

```
SELECT day,TotalProfit, TotalRevenue, TotalProfit/TotalRevenue AS ProfitMargin
from (
SELECT 

        day,
        SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit,
        SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue
    FROM table
GROUP BY day
) as subq
```

Ofcourse I agree with others it looks an overhead

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,TotalProfit/TotalRevenue AS ProfitMargin from
 (select
    day,
    SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit,
    SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue       
FROM table) x
where
```

Comment: Yu cannot refer Alias in Select clause

Comment: you can if the table is contained in parens. try it.

Comment: @CodyThompson The issue is that `TotalProfit` and `TotalRevenue` are aliases.  You're directly referencing them in the `SELECT` of the same query they were defined.  This would have the exact same issue the OP is trying to resolve.

Comment: Outer query can reference Total Profit or Total Revenue.

Comment: WOOPS sorry, is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subquery. 
Then you can use `data.TotalProfit / data.TotalRevenue AS ProfitMargin`

```
SELECT 
   data.day
 , data.TotalProfit
 , data.TotalRevenue
 , (data.TotalProfit / data.TotalRevenue) AS ProfitMargin
FROM (
  SELECT
      day    
    , SUM(profit) AS TotalProfit
    , SUM(revenue) AS TotalRevenue
  FROM 
   table
)
 data
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method for doing this is a lateral join.  This looks like:

```
SELECT . . . ,
       v.exp1, v.exp2, v.exp1 / v.exp2
FROM table t, LATERAL
     (VALUES (<expression1>, <expression2>) ) v(exp1, exp2);
```

However, to use this with an aggregation query, you would need a subquery anyway.  And if you are using a subquery, just put the calculation in the outer query.