# How to run calculation on returned columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this SQL which works great. It gets total amount people have bet and total they have won. I want to do some math on these values to return their ROI.

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'win' THEN amount * odds - (amount * bonus) END) AS amountwon,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'pending' AND bonus = 0 THEN amount END) AS amountbet
FROM
  bets 
INNER JOIN users ON bets.user = users.id
WHERE
  club = 2 
GROUP BY
  user
ORDER BY roi DESC
```

I tried this but no luck

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'win' THEN amount * odds - (amount * bonus) END) AS amountwon,
  SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'pending' AND bonus = 0 THEN amount END) AS amountbet,
  COALESCE(((SUM(amountwon) * 100.0) / NULLIF(SUM(amountbet), 0)),
                100) AS roi
FROM
  bets 
INNER JOIN users ON bets.user = users.id
WHERE
  club = 2 
GROUP BY
  user
ORDER BY roi DESC
```

How can I use those returned values amountwon and amountbet on a new column based of those values?

Thanks

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'amountwon' in fieldlist

Comment: you can use subqueries: SELECT COALESCE.... FROM (your original query)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16460086/1312382) might be of help, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use aggregate function `SUM` on amountwon and amountbet because it on same query. Use subqueries instead

```
select *, COALESCE(((SUM(amountwon) * 100.0) / NULLIF(SUM(amountbet), 0)),
                100) AS roi
from (
    your first query
)
```

Comment: This gets the error `every derived table must have it's own value`. Sorry i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @MomasVII `FROM(SELECT ...) AS someTableName`

Answer (score 1):

For readability you can use a *cte* to first calculate your values, something like:

```
with cte as (
    select
        Sum(case when B.result = 'win' then B.amount * B.odds - (B.amount * B.bonus) end) as amountwon,
        Sum(case when B.result <> 'pending' and B.bonus = 0 then B.amount end) as amountbet
    from bets b inner join users u on b.user = u.id
    where u.club = 2 
    group by b.user
)

select *,
Coalesce(((amountwon * 100.0) / NullIf(amountbet, 0)), 100) as roi
from cte
order by roi desc
```

Note also the use of short meaningful *aliases* to make it easier to read

Comment: You wouldn't need the sums on `amountwon` and `amountbet` any more, they are a single values already.

Comment: Yes of course I have corrected, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH` clause can be used for this purpose

```
WITH amounts(user_id, won, bet) AS (
    SELECT
        user,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'win' THEN amount * odds - (amount * bonus) END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'pending' AND bonus = 0 THEN amount END)
    FROM bets
    GROUP BY user
)
SELECT *, COALESCE(won*100.0/NULLIF(bet, 0) as roi from amounts order by roi;
```

Alternatively you can use a sub-query:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(won*100.0/NULLIF(bet, 0) as roi from (
    SELECT
        user,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'win' THEN amount * odds - (amount * bonus) END) as won,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result <> 'pending' AND bonus = 0 THEN amount END) as bet
    FROM bets
    GROUP BY user
) as amounts;
```

In both cases you can now easily join above temporary `amounts` with the `user` table to fetch in further information.